# "Gnome 2.28.2: LCtrl+LShift as a combination to change layout" Issue

Tags: linux, shell, gnome, hotkeys

I am used to change the layout using keys combination `CTRL + SHIFT`. Not to mention that lots of applications use that combination as a part of another complex combination. Say - `CTRL + SHIFT + TAB` in Firefox to select previous tab or `CTRL + SHIFT + left|right arrow` to select whole world.

So here comes the issue in Gnome2. If I have the `CTRL + SHIFT` as a hotkey to change layout then no other combination with `CTRL + SHIFT` will work. `CTRL + SHIFT + TAB` does not work. `CTRL + SHIFT + right arrow` does not work. In Windows that works fine though.

Removing such combination as hotkey solves the problem. But I still want to use old good `CTRL` and `SHIFT`.

Is there any patch or configuration tips to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have programming skills i would have a look at xbindkeys source code. Seems it's one step away from being able to help here:

```
$ xbindkeys --key
```

is able to recognize CTRL + SHIFT and outputs a keycode for it (however weird: control+shift + shift or something similar), but if you try to use it in a .xbindkeysrc it doesn't work (doesn't catch it) most likely because we're dealing with modifier keys here.

If my understanding is correct, xbindkeys needs to react to this sequence:

- Control and Shift keypresses (any order)
- Control and Shift keyreleases (any order)
- and no other key event in between

Only then do we know it's not a Ctrl+Shift+a or something...